# UK citizen traveling back into US

Tags: visas, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I'm a UK citizen studying in NY, my student visa runs out in September. I was thinking to go to Canada (for example) and apply for a tourist visa back into the US. Does anyone know how long I would have to be out of the US to apply? How long does the application take and so on?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you plan to continue studying? Or is the idea that your studies will be done in September and you want to come back to the US as a tourist? You don't have to leave the US when your visa expires (this is different from many other countries), but you do have to leave when you are out of "status," which for a student visa occurs when your school reports that you are finished or have left your program.

Comment: Furthermore, you do not need a tourist visa if you want to return to the US for less than 90 days, as you can enter under the Visa Waiver Program.  If you want to stay longer, you need B-2 status.  You don't actually need to leave the US when you are out of status, as @ZachLipton says, because you can apply to change your status while remaining in the US.  This could be more expensive than a trip to Canada, however, so most people seem to change status by leaving, applying for a new visa, and re-entering.

Comment: In short, please tell us exactly what your situation is and what you're looking to do, because it's pretty confusing right now.

Comment: thank you. So I'm a student at the moment, with an F1 visa. My course finishes on the 15th august, I have to be out of the us by the 12th Sep. I would like to come back to the US, but 90 days would be fine.. What would be my cheapest option?

Comment: basically i would just like to stay for a month or so longer...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return as a visitor to the US after Aug 15th and for just a month, there's two things you can do:

1- File an I-539 form to change to a [B1/B2 status](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/C2en.pdf)<sup>*</sup>

2- Go across the border to Canada and re-enter the US under the VWP which you're entitled to as a [UK citizen](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html)

<sup>* *Note that you're still out of status even if you have timely applied for a change. Since you have to mail the application, that could be slower than the second option*</sup>

Comment: Note: if you are entering the USA via land you do not even need an ESTA.

Comment: Can I apply for vwp from the US? And do I have to be out of the US for a particular amount of time before re entering?

Comment: @BeatriceScirocchi you can't really apply for VWP, it's the program which allows you to enter the US without a visa, and is essentially the same as a B1/B2 status. There's technically no amount of time you have to wait, but the border official will probably ask questions

Comment: Yeah you're biggest issue is that the VWP requires that you demonstrate that you are a short-term visitor who will return home and not live in the United States. As a recent US student, you likely have a bunch of ties to the US and few ties to your home country. You may well face questions from the border officials, and it would help to have strong reasons why you will return home: e.g. you're starting a job in a month (and here's proof of that) or you're starting another course of studies (and here's proof of that).

Comment: "you're still out of status even if you have timely applied for a change and they can have you removed": The US doesn't remove people solely for being out of status if they have a pending change of status application.

Comment: @phoog *"Your lawful nonimmigrant status ends and you are out of status
when your Form I-94 expires, even if you have timely applied
to change your nonimmigrant status. Generally, as a matter of
discretion, USCIS will defer any removal proceedings until after
the petition is adjudicated and USCIS decides your change of
nonimmigrant status request. Nevertheless, DHS may bring a
removal proceeding against you, even if you have an application for
change of status pending."* from the link in the A

Comment: @phoog that's why I said they can and not they will

Comment: Okay, but the way you put it made it sound like she'd need to be worried about a significant risk of being deported, when in fact the risk would be exceedingly low.  Also, if she leaves the US after August 15th, she cannot re-enter in F-1 status, so your answer should read "If you want to return as a visitor to the US after August 15th...".

Comment: @phoog clarified :)

Comment: So just to clarify. I don't have to do anything until I get to the border control in canada,when coming back to the US.. and then fingers crossed they let me in?

Comment: @BeatriceScirocchi as suggested above, I would prepare something to prove you're eventually returning to the UK. Technically it should be ok, but final decision always lies with the immigration officer

Comment: Sure I understand that. One last thing sorry! Is esta a different thing? Or do I need that too?

Comment: @BeatriceScirocchi ESTA is different, but you don't need it if you're travelling by land to the US